# R table without 0 value

Tags: r

I have created two variables

```
> Ntimes <- c(0:9)
> frequency <-c(2,4,4,8,4,5,2,4,2,1)
```

and made a table out of them

```
> table5 <- table(Ntimes,frequency)
```

Which displays

```
> head(table5)

      frequency
Ntimes 1 2 4 5 8
     0 0 1 0 0 0
     1 0 0 1 0 0
     2 0 0 1 0 0
     3 0 0 0 0 1
     4 0 0 1 0 0
     5 0 0 0 1 0
```

However, I would like to not have a matrix but have it in the style of

```
N times   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Frequency 2 4 4 8 4 5 2 4 2 1
```

It could be in columns I don't mind.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ntimes <- c(0:9)
frequency <-c(2,4,4,8,4,5,2,4,2,1)
```

To get them as columns, combine your two vectors into a dataframe.

```
data.frame(Ntimes,frequency)
   Ntimes frequency
1       0         2
2       1         4
3       2         4
4       3         8
5       4         4
6       5         5
7       6         2
8       7         4
9       8         2
10      9         1
```

To get them as rows, you can use rbind. Stacks one row or dataframe under another.

```
rbind(Ntimes,frequency)
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
Ntimes       0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
frequency    2    4    4    8    4    5    2    4    2     1
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use the mean and got 4.05, but with a calculator I got 3.944. Do you know which is correct?

Comment: The mean of all 20 numbers is 4.05  
The mean of each column can be gotten with   apply(mydf,2,mean)  where mydf <- data.frame(Ntimes,frequency)      summary(mydf) will also give you means of each column in a dataframe.

Comment: You want a weighted mean so the correct is 3.944. Try `weighted.mean` in r